# how to get my android to boot up and shutdown automatically

Tags: boot, automation, shutdown

I want my android phone to boot up (I expect from a low energy state rather than off) automatically, run my app for a while, shutdown (ie return to low energy state) and repeat at intervals, say an hour.  Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: alcaltel pop c3 has a scheduler which will turn off your phone and turn on your phone at set times (once a day).  I'm not sure how it does this. it must either be in some low energy state (which im going to try and measure) or it is psompted on by some other hardware with a clock???

Answer (score 0):

The only "low energy states" I know Android uses is having certain components disabled (e.g. switched off WiFi, Bluetooth, NFC, whatever, plus dimmed the screen, etc.) – so we certainly cannot speak from "boot up".

On that condition, there are many apps available for Android which could be used. You've already put the [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) tag to your question. Following up [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) should give some pointers (Oh! None? OK, wait a few minutes, I'll update it).

- [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) is the most extensive and flexible app in this field. Tons of addons even enhance its capacity: enable/disable things and dim the screen are "peanuts" for it. For a collection of tutorials, available addons, and more, be welcome to my [Tasker Resource Collection](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker).
- as you're asking about a time-based schedule, [Timeriffic](http://www.appbrain.com/app/timeriffic/com.alfray.timeriffic) should be worth a look as well. Not that mighty as *Tasker* – but free.
- [llama](/questions/tagged/llama) is another alternative. Again free, and comes a little closer to *Tasker's* capabilities (though not quire reaching them).

Note however that certain things depend on your device capabilities as well as on the Android version running. With recent versions, your device must be rooted to allow an app toggling airplane mode, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Automateit can do that (of course, rooting is required!). Here is the link for the free version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage

Comment: We discourage link-only answers on this site. It would help if you could post exact steps required to make this happen.